# pax-run using Maven Plugin in pom.xml

Tags: maven-2, osgi, apache-felix

How can I execute **Pax-Runner** tasks using a **Maven Plugin**, which I can specify in the `pom.xml` file?

i.e. I can do the following in command line using Pax-Runner (to convert a war file into an OSGi bundle)

```
pax-run war:file:C:/somefile.war warref:C:/somefile.properties
```

What should I do to make it happen in a pom.xml file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The links in the accepted answer are broken. Could you please improve it with the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [maven plugin for pax](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/run-mojo.html). I've not used it, but according to the documentation it does what you need. On the usage page there's a section titled [Using the Pax Plugin inside a POM](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/usage.html) that describes how to set up your project.